# C++ - Removing a specific smart pointer from a vector

Tags: c++

I am working on an entity component system at the moment. Each entity has a vector of `unique_ptr`s to components (I have a base class call `Component` which each component inherits from. There's also an `std::bitset` and an `std::array` of components as well. To add a component, I do this:

```
template <typename T, typename... TArgs>
void add(TArgs&&... mArgs) {
    if (!componentBitset[getComponentTypeID<T>()]) { // make sure entity doesn't already have this component

        T* c(new T(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)...)); // create component
        c->object = this; // set the component's pointer to its parent entity
        std::unique_ptr<Component>uPtr{ c };
        components.emplace_back(std::move(uPtr));

        componentArray[getComponentTypeID<T>()] = c; // add to the std::array
        componentBitset[getComponentTypeID<T>()] = true; // set the bitset

        c->init(); // initialise the new component
    }
    else {
        // ...Object already has the component
    }
}
```

This gets called with:
`entity->add<*component type*>(*constructor arguments*);`

My question is: How can I remove components using a template? Removing from the `std::array` isn't necessary, since it will be overwritten if it doesn't exist in the bitset. I know how to set the bitset, I just need to know how I can remove the component from the vector.

```
template <typename T> void remove() {
    // remove from vector here

    componentBitset[getComponentTypeID<T>()] = false;
}
```

Comment: Were you looking for `vector::erase(iterator)`?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep think so, I'm just not sure how to use it in this case

Comment: Unrelated: Look into `std::make_unique`. When you `new`, play around with other stuff, and then pop the allocation into the `unique_ptr`, you have this great hole where somehting could go wrong and leak the allocation. If you `make_unique`, you have the `unique_ptr` from the get-go.

Comment: The example of `remove_if` at the bottom of [this document page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) should set you on a good path.

Comment: What's the parameter you were looking to be passed to your `remove()` function, if any?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I'm not looking to pass anything. I want to call it like `entity->remove<*component type*>()`

Comment: You should be able to just iterate through you vector, get their typeinfo and compare them with `T` with something like `std::type_index(typeid(T)) == std::type_index(typeid(*it))`